# How can I exclude a div from a fixed position background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a full page image background to work with a theme and its giving me issues. When I use `position: fixed` on the background it completely covers the top nav and header.

I know there is a different way of getting this done, but after hours on stack and w3 I cant get it solved. Thanks for the help.

Site: www.klondike-klinkers.com

Code I've used that covers the header:

```
<div id="bg">
    <img src="http://www.klondike-klinkers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Dollarphotoclub_10621667-1-1.jpg" alt="">
```

```css
#bg {
    position: fixed; 
    top: -50%; 
    left: -50%; 
    width: 200%; 
    height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    margin: auto; 
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You do not really need an absolute positioned div if you just want to add bg to body. After looking at your site I can say that it can be done via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
body.custom-background {
    background-image: url('http://www.klondike-klinkers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Dollarphotoclub_10621667-1-1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.page-wrapper {
    background: transparent !important;
}
.header-wrapper {
    background: #fff !important;
}
.header2 {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
.container, .copyright {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Make sure the css is added at the end so it overwrites the legenda theme's css. You do not need to add "!important" if you que the CSS at the end.

---

Optionally if you want to style your fixed div you can use the following codes:

Add this html inside `page-wrapper`after `header-wrapper`

```
<div id="bg">    
    <img src="http://www.klondike-klinkers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Dollarphotoclub_10621667-1-1.jpg" alt="" scale="0">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    z-index: 0;
}

#bg img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
}

.header2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
   }
.header2, .container, .copyright {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    background: #fff;
   }
```

---

Make sure you get rid of the last row and margin-bottom from your visual composer. I would also recommend adding white background using visual composer itself.

Comment: This worked perfectly with the header except it completely covered the body content and footer now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your issue on the site you linked, but have you tried setting a `z-index` value on the nav/header to place them higher than the background?

Comment: I had to take the background away since the site is in a hap hazard state of live at the moment. I was trying to just test things to get it working first. I am not familiar with z-index. I will need to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using in the CSS for the class you want to bring in front.

```
z-index: 1;
```

z-index allows your divs to overlap each other. It depends on what value you assign it. If you give it a 1 then by default it will be in front of everything else that you want to display. But if you make your z-index: -1; then it will be behind. You can also make one div have z-index: 3, and 1 div have z-index: 1. So the one with the 3 for z-index will be overlapped over the div that has 1 for z-index.